# How to skip some text of using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from this website and create a Dataframe. However, I want to remove the text 'Description' in the row of the Description column. What is the solution to remove it?

The code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


records = []
tickers = ['FSLR']

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/profile?p={}'

for s in tickers:
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(s,s)).content, 'html.parser')

    records.append({
        'symbol' : s,
        'Name': soup.h1.text,
        'Sector': soup.select_one('span:contains("Sector(s)") + span').text,
        'Industry': soup.select_one('span:contains("Industry") + span').text,
        'Description' : soup.find('section', {'class':'quote-sub-section Mt(30px)'}).text

    })

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.head()
```

I want the output like this:

```
        symbol  Name                      Sector        Industry
0       FSLR    First Solar, Inc. (FSLR)  Technology    Solar

Description
First Solar, Inc. provides photovol...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the description field is inside the `<p>` tag under the section that you are currently capturing.

```
<section class="quote-sub-section Mt(30px)" data-reactid="216">
    <h2 class="Fz(m) Lh(1) Fw(b) Mt(0) Mb(18px)" data-reactid="217">…</h2>
    <p class="Mt(15px) Lh(1.6)" data-reactid="219">…</p>
</section>
```

So you can grab the `<p>` by using:

`description = soup.find("section", {'class': 'quote-sub-section Mt(30px)'}).find("p").text`

Doing so will get rid of the string 'Description'.

Comment: Thanks for your help